# how to get current logged in user resource with django-tastypie

Tags: session, backbone.js, tastypie

I am using backbone.js with django and i would like to right after the initial request to my application `/` get the current logged in user.

I do have a `UserResource` set up so i can make an api call `api/v1/user/id` but that means i have to know the `id` i am looking for which i dont. In traditional django request views, i would have the `request.user` object. Is this also available to me on the client side and if not how can i make a call to get `request.user`?

Edit:

Since i am using traditional authentication with Django and after authorizing the user, backbone picks up from there. Can i in my base.html file, create a variable that stores the unique id of the current logged in user like so:

```
var user = {{user}}; // which shows the username
```

Are there any risks to this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the 'Creating per-user resources' example in the TastyPie Cookbook

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#creating-per-user-resources

However, the docs are out-of-date, and the API has changed. The method signatures have changed, and the request is now an attribute of the bundle.

def authorized_read_list(self, object_list, bundle):

You can access the user from `bundle.request.user`

Also see https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/809

Comment: Thanks for the response, i am using the traditional django authentication/authorization technique to get my user logged in and not backbone.js (make an api call to UserResource or something). Even with the per user resource are you suggesting i just on login make an extra call out to tastypie and get back all user and with the per user resource, i would only get one json object back?

Comment: If you are using a standard django login, then the session cookie will  identify the user for you in any subsequent AJAX requests just like with standard HTTP request. Your initial TastyPie call could return the userResource as additional data whatever else you are bringing back.

Comment: any examples of javascript calling to the session cookie and retrieving the user id or username?

Comment: The cookbook sample seems to be outdated. apply_authorization_limits is deprecated. Override read_list in your authorization class instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884529/how-to-filter-objects-by-user-id-with-tastypie/16957412

Answer (score 0):

The following would place the user id in the meta of the response:

```
def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data_dict):
    if isinstance(data_dict, dict):
        if 'meta' in data_dict:
            if request.user and request.user.pk:
                data_dict['meta']['user_id'] = request.user.pk

    return data_dict
```

Personally, I've never had a need to do this. I place the user object into page context server side. Even for a single page RESTful application I would make standard request/response (not AJAX) on login, and populate the content/context server side.

Any subsequent AJAX requests **should not** include the user id in the same way that the suer id should not be passed in the URL. You should identify the user server-side and filter accordingly. Django makes this very easy, exposing the user using the AuthenticationMiddleware.

Comment: "Personally, I've never had a need to do this". I don't know if you have ever used Django with backbone, and if you have please let me know what a more proper way would be to get on initial load, the current logged in user. I know on the server side, i am able to use request.user or {{ user }} but without reading the session or placing a <script> tag in my base.html file and adding a global variable, i am not sure of any other ways?

Comment: I think i understand what your saying now, instead of filtering with the user object on the client side,  i should make my request as usual and do the filtering on the server side